# Тире или дефис между словами подогрев(-)выдержка(-)охлаждение

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Как правильно писать слова в скобках: нужно поставить дефис или тире? Каким правилом объясняется? "Кроме обычного протекания процесса (подогрев-выдержка-охлаждение), возможны комплексные температурные программы..."

Comment: Исправьте в заголовке: охлАждение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для усиления выразительности и интонационного членения допускается постановка тире между однородными членами предложения: Все говорят одно и то же: Распутин **— царица — немцы — война — революция (М. Г.); Вспоминается цепь событий: приезд Веры — знакомство — разговоры о литературе и искусстве — объяснение — отказ — расставание.**

См.:  [Розенталь. Д.Э. Справочник по пунктуации.](http://orthographia.ru/go.php?url=http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=97#pp97)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь скорее дефис. Все зависит от того, как понимает автор то, что у него в скобках. Если это единый процесс из трех компонентов или стадий, то все вместе - название этого процесса, одно слово, значит дефис. Если же это *разные* процессы, то да, возможно тире.

В пользу первой версии, то есть дефиса, говорит единственное число и общий технический смысл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ещё интересует может ли это быть приложением?

Comment: @Cтася, нет, на приложение это не похоже. Во-первых, несогласованное, ибо вообще нет главного слова как такового, а во-вторых, заключенное в скобки обычно не рассматривается на предмет синтаксической связи с остальной частью. Не было бы скобок - и падеж был бы родительным. Хотя я как-то раньше не задумывался, могу ошибаться.